# How to free of memory directshow filters

Tags: c++, winapi, com, directshow

I'm currently working on a small program using directshow library.The program among others should be able to select any camera connected to computer and record stream. 
My problem is that I'm not sure how to free of memory dshow filters.
Let's give you an example:

For example when I want to set the output filename I have to create an AVI Mux filter like so:

```
IBaseFilter * aviMux;
bGraph->SetOutputFileName(
    &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,   
    L"example.avi",  
    &aviMux,       
    NULL);
```

Now I'd like to change the filename and use the SetOutputFileName() function again, but how to free of memory AVI Mux (by the way obviously the function creates a FileWriter filter as well which I'd like to free as well)? Only I can do is that:

```
aviMux->Release();
fGraph->RemoveFilter(aviMux);
```

But will the memory be freed before the end of the program now? I'd like to do something like this:

```
delete aviMux;
```

but that's an error obviously.
Thanks in advice for any answers and help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard COM rules apply:

- you don't need an interface pointer anymore - you do `IUnkonwn::Release`
- once you want to explicitly stop filter graph activity - you do `IGraphBuilder::Stop` to stop the filters
- as soon as you release all interface pointers you hold to the graph and filters and their interfaces, all underlying resources are freed automatically

To make it more reliable you can also consider removing all filters from stopped graph explicitly (which internally forces pin disconnection).

Specifically to capture filter graph, changing a file name is almost the same complexity as building new graph from scratch. So this is what makes sense to do: stop, full cleanup, new graph, start new capture to new file. Reusing filters is possible (using [`IFileSinkFilter::SetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a filter writer already added to stopped filter graph), however it is unlikely to speed up file switch any visibly - there will anyway be a certain delay involved.

For a seamless file switch you need two graphs - a capture graph, and a writing graph. And communication between the two, such as [bridging](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's just brilliant and exactly what I needed! I knew that I could just had been releasing the whole old graph and building a new one, but I couldn't deal with that I didn't know if it's the best or the only way. Your answer explains everything, thanks a lot again!